# Pythonic way of converting a list to inputs of a function of several variables

Tags: python, idioms

I'm beginning to feel a little dumb for not figuring this out...

say I have a function of two variables:

```
def testfun(x,y):
    return x*y
```

now I have a list of values, say `[2,3]`, which I want to input as values into the function. What's the most Pythonic way to do this? I thought of something like this:

```
def listfun(X):
    X_as_strs = str(X).strip('[]')
    expression = 'testfun({0})'.format(X_as_strs)
    return eval(expression)
```

... but it looks very un-pythonic and I don't want to deal with strings anyway! Is there a one liner (e.g.) that will make me feel all tingly and cuddly inside (like so often happens with Python)? I have a feeling it could be something crazy obvious...

Comment: `testfun(*[2, 3])`?

Comment: dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12786102/748858

Comment: uum yes thanks! Wow, I can't believe I didn't know that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` notation will serve you well here.

```
def testfun(x,y):
    return x*y

def listfun(X):
    return testfun(*X)

>>> testlist = [3,5]
>>> listfun(testlist)
15
>>> testfun(*testlist)
15
```

The `*` notation is designed specifically for unpacking lists for function calls. I haven't seen it work in any other context, but calling `testfun(*[3,5])` is equivalent to calling `testfun(3,5)`.