# zip two values from the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to zip two values in a dictionary using Python numpy but it's not very successful. What I mean by zipping is something like this:

1. I have a dictionary called dict, and inside looks like `{'a0': [1, 2, 3], 'a1': [4, 5, 6]}`.
2. Then I want to zip this dictionary dict values to: `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`  (one element from each key)

Comment: `zip(*your_dict.values())`

Comment: That was my attempt but it didn't give me what I want.. It was like [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]

Comment: Oh.. wait star in the front.. Thank you! I didn't know about this star in the front. It works! Thanks

Comment: the 'star in front' unpacks the items from the sequence given by `your_dict.values()` and turns them into separate arguments which are passed to the `zip` function. Please read [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786102/unpacking-function-argument)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to *unpack* `dict.values()` when passing onto `zip()` . Example -

```
>>> d = {'a0': [1, 2, 3], 'a1': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> zip(*d.values())
[(4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3)]
```

Please note using this method, the order of elements in the zipped inner lists are not guaranteed, as dictionary itself does not have any sense of order.

If you want a specific order, you would need to be explicit in your `zip()` call. Example -

```
>>> zip(d['a0'], d['a1'])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: There's no way to sort this automatically by the dict keys? For a large dictionary, this is not suitable.