# What is the meaning of * in python functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
print(*cmath.polar(cnum), sep ='\n')
```

I just came across this line while solving a complex number problem.
What is the use of `*` before `cmath`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786102/unpacking-function-argument

Comment: A better question to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Comment: @maniexx I think the question I dupped is a bit better, your one deals with `*` and `**` in the definition of functions (mostly). Good link for the OP to read if he wants to, though.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, this one is even better, but it was earlier duped to a pretty bad one.