# How print tabs (long spaces) between 2 characters of a string, in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, loops

How print tabs (long spaces) between 2 characters of a string, in Python using loops and not the "\t" tab?
(or in loops, if possible")
For Example :

`a="HELLO"`
so the output must be

```
H        E         L        L       O
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not using the `"\t"` tab" ?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh means i dont want to use "\t" (backslash tab) in the print statements, just create a space tab anywhere. I want solutions using loops

Comment: A [tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) isn't simply a sequence of spaces. Do you mean that you want to print each char in a string so that it's [left-justified](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) in a field of a given width? There are several ways to do that efficiently in Python.

Comment: I'm unclear as to how you intend to print a tab character without ever using that character in your code.  "Using loops" doesn't change the problem, any more than it would for any other character.  Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack the string into it's characters and use tabs as a separator in the call to `print`

```
a="HELLO"
print(*a, sep="\t")
# H       E       L       L       O
```

If you want to handle the string with the tab-separated letters, you can instead use `str.join`

```
tab_separated = '\t'.join(a)
```

A looping solution would be very inefficient, but would look something like

```
def tab_sep(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    res = s[0]
    for letter in s[1:]:
        res += '\t' + letter
    return res
```

You can replace the `'\t'` strings in the above with `chr(9)`(tab has the ASCII value 9) if you really don't want the escape sequences, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It makes it difficult to tell what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! but please can you explain what does the * operator do. What is its function here?

Comment: @user9969041 Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters and the links on that page. And in the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: @user9969041 This is called argument unpacking.  We take the iterable `a` (a string) and unpack it so that each of its elements is a separate argument to `print`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786141/6779307

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `join` method:

```
spacer = '    '
seq = 'Hello'
print(spacer.join(seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this by importing sys if you would like to only print as `print` includes new line for every sentence, but `sys.stdout.write` doesnt

```
a="HELLO"
import sys
for num in range(len(a)):
#    print('\t %s' %(a[num]))
    sys.stdout.write('\t %s' %(a[num]))
```