# Using a field from CSV errors my previously working code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on sending emails with python and have a decent grasp on that however I am struggling with using info from a CSV File.
I have a piece of code:

```
 s.login('example@gmail.com', 'expassword')
```

that when used with a preset login and password works, it sends the email to my recipient, which is later set in my code, however as soon as I use the code:(chooses a random email and password from a CSV to send from(for a spam email demo))

```
with open ('C:/Filepath/randomsender.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    sender = random.choice(list(reader))
```

followed by

```
s.login(sender)
```

I get an auth error because it cannot read the chosen line properly even though the result of sender is formatted the same as:

```
'example@gmail.com', 'expassword'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass list elements as position param, you need to unpack it.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786102/unpacking-function-argument) might help

e.g.

```
s.login(*sender)
```