# Tuple to Set as coordinates

Tags: python

I have a tuple, which gives me something like this:

`(array([115, 115, 295], dtype=int64), array([377, 378,404], dtype=int64))`

Now I want to convert it as a set like this:

`{(115,377),(115,378),(295,404)}`

I'm currently using this approach :

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    l = int(len(edges[0]))
    res=set()
    for i in range (0,len):
        res.add((edges[0][i],edges[1][i]))
    return res
```

[Code link](https://ideone.com/6tRup2)

But gives me error.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\canny_vertices.py", line 40, in  print(edges2cordinate(indices))
  File "F:\canny_vertices.py", line 16, in edges2cordinate for i in range (0,len):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*

What am I missing ?

Comment: No links to the code, paste your entire code here please!

Comment: Which python version are you using. 2 or 3? Don't tag both of them.

Comment: code added, please see again

Comment: I have 2.7 in desktop and 3 in laptop , so i need both :p

Comment: do you mean to use l instead of len for the range?

Comment: To point out the main error in your current implementation, it's saying that `len` is a built-in, not an `int`, so you probably meant `l`

Comment: What is `edges` variable look like?

Comment: yes @aws_apprentice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous code, you would want to do `range (0,l)` instead of `range (0,len)`, since you have saved your length variable in `l`, so you want to pass that length to the `range` variable instead of inbuilt function `len`

Once you do that, the original code works fine

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    l = int(len(edges[0]))
    res=set()
    for i in range (0,l):
        res.add((edges[0][i],edges[1][i]))
    return res

print(edges2cordinate([[115, 115, 295],[377, 378,404]]))
```

The output will be `{(295, 404), (115, 378), (115, 377)}`

But this can also be easily done via `zip`, where we unpack the list of lists, pass it to `zip` as an argument, and then convert the zipped iterator back to `set`, note that we see an unordered output here due to `set`

```
li = [[115, 115, 295],[377, 378,404]]

print(set(zip(*li)))
```

Output will be `{(295, 404), (115, 378), (115, 377)}`

To reverse the items, just reverse them when creating the set via list-comprehension by reversing individual elements of the tuple!

```
li = [[115, 115, 295],[377, 378,404]]

print(set((y,x) for x, y in zip(*li)))
```

The output will be `{(404, 295), (377, 115), (378, 115)}`

Comment: Given that the OP is errouneously passing the `len` function, to range, perhaps you should consider not just giving them a one-liner which they likely won't even understand or at least explain what they did wrong and how your solution works

Comment: Fixed @juanpa.arrivillaga please have a look and see if looks better :)

Comment: How can I reverse each one of them, like from `(295, 404)` to `(404, 295)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` with unpacking:

```
list(zip(*tupl))  # where tupl is your tuple
```

which outputs a list of values as oppose to your expectation. But I guess this is probably more suited as set will remove duplicates and has no order.

Answer (score 0):

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    res = set()
    for i in range(len(edges[0])):
        res.add((edges[0][i], edges[1][i]))
    return res

edge = ([115, 123, 295], [377, 378, 404])
res = edges2cordinate(edge)
set(reversed(list(res)))
```

This also gives the correct output `{(115, 377), (115, 378), (295, 404)}`, which is a simpler solution if you are not familiar with `zip`. The reason your code did not work properly was correctly answered above.

Answer (score 0):

to explain how to get between all of the other answers, we start with a tidied up (and fixed) version of the OPs original code:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    num_entries = len(edges[0])
    res = set()
    for i in range(0, num_entries):
        res.add((edges[0][i], edges[1][i]))
    return res
```

the first cleanup happens after noticing that `range()` allows a single argument to be passed, causing it to count from zero up to that argument.  we also notice that `num_entries` is only used once, so we can move it to where it's used, giing us:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    res = set()
    for i in range(len(edges[0])):
        res.add((edges[0][i], edges[1][i]))
    return res
```

second, notice that we keep getting the first and second elements of `edges` on every iteration of the `for` loop.  Python gives us "[assignment expressions](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/)" ([PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)) which lets us write this as:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    first_arr, second_arr = edges
    res = set()
    for i in range(len(first)):
        res.add((first_arr[i], second_arr[i]))
    return res
```

and should be a bit faster, because we only need to get the items out once rather than every loop iteration.

every answer has pointed to using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to make this code more concise.  you use `zip` by giving it multiple things that can be iterated over, like `list`s or your arrays, and it zips them giving you back tuples containing items from the things you gave it.  e.g:

```
list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
```

evaluates to `[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]`.  the reason for the `list()` surrounding it is that (in Python 3) `zip` gives you back an iterator, and passing this iterator to `list()` gives you a list containing items from that iterator.

third, the smallest change to use `zip` on the above code would be:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    first_arr, second_arr = edges
    res = set()
    for first_item_i, second_item_i in zip(first_arr, second_arr):
        res.add((first_item_i, second_item_i))
    return res
```

further, we're using these "assignment expressions" to redundantly take things apart and put them together, so we can rewrite this to:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    res = set()
    for pair_i in zip(edges[0], edges[1]):
        res.add(pair_i)
    return res
```

we can also change to using `zip(*edges)` which "[unpacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786141/1358308)" `edges` into the arguments to `zip`, i.e. `edges[0]` goes to the first parameter of `zip`, `edges[1]` goes to the second parameter, etc.

another tool Python gives you are [generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/1358308), which lets us turn lots of this into one line:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    return set(pair_i for pair_i in zip(*edges))
```

but we aren't "doing anything" with this generator expression, so it can be removed, getting to the minimalist:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    return set(zip(*edges))
```

in a follow-up comment, you asked how to reverse the order of the edges.  one way would be to do:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    return set(zip(edges[1], edges[0]))
```

which will hopefully do the obvious thing.  the suggested [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function probably does what you'd expect, but can be used as:

```
def edges2cordinate(edges):
    return set(zip(*reversed(edges)))
```

to keep it minimal